# Rules Of Fantasy Story?

Tags: style, fantasy

What The Perfect Rules Or Perfect Template To Write A fantasy story..

> what I most Reading?
>   From Where I start The story?
>   What I need Before writing fantasy?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is an extremely broad question. If you can narrow it down, we might be able to help you, or you might find an answer in one of the other questions in the fantasy tag.

Comment: If you want to write fantasy read it: Robin Hobb, Brandon Sanderson, JRR Tolkein, Raymond E Fesit, Ursula LeGuin, China Meiville, Peter V Brett, David Eddings, Stephen R. Donaldson… Hell, even Stephen King wrote a fantasy series. If you do you'll notice that Fantasy is a very loose term and basically covers everything that isn't Modern or Futuristic (and yes, Urban and SciFi Fantasy are indeed  real things!)

Comment: You're getting dinged (question and answer) because this is a writer's forum.  As such it deals with form, the difficult and extensive subject of defining good writing.  Your question is one of formula - as in formulaic.  Thus your question seems to ask, "what's the simple secret to good (fantasy) writing?"  Simply put, there is no secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfect template to write fantasy is:

- use a medieval world
- add magic, dragons, faeries and/or other supernatural elements
- have a hero complete a quest
- add some romance

Comment: Your first bullet excludes Urban Fantasy (set in contemporary times). Your last bullet is not required. "Hero" really should be "hero/ine," but that's me nitpicking. :)

Comment: Agreed, fantasy is a loose term that can apply to a wide range of settings. Brandon Sanderson's Mist Born is set in a Victorian era world and Warbreaker is feudal. Raymond E. Feist and Janny Wurts' Empire trilogy is set in a feudal Japan style setting! Some of the best fantasy is *not* medieval, and most of the worst *is*! Super natural elements are not required (though it does help), the setting is what makes it Fantasy. Quest and hero is not needed either, the first book of Kate Miller's Godspeaker trilogy is entirely about the lead growing up, as are the Assassin's books by Robin Hobb

Comment: In fairness, I'm not sure if he meant "all fantasy stories must follow this template" or "this is A template for a fantasy story that I think is a pretty good one". In any case, though, stories written from a template tend to sound like they are stories written from a template.

Comment: @Jay, I was going by the words "perfect template" ;) True enough mind you; templates equal uniformity and the best works are often the ones that do something original.

Comment: I understand the template of a genre to be a simplified prototype, not a motif index. Sir Gawain killing the Green Knight only to discover himself and similar tales are the prototype from which the genre grew.

Comment: @CLockeWork I have to say I thought the supernatural element was really the only inviolable one. Can you cite a fantasy without a supernatural element?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum, it's certainly the most common element, and off the top of my head the only one I can think of is Scott Lynch's Locke Lamora series (1400 Venetian style setting, no magic or creatures.) I did find [this list](http://www.stackedbooks.org/2014/02/fantasy-without-magic.html) though

Comment: If I was looking for an example of mockery, this answer would fit perfectly. Since there are thousands (of thousands) readers, publishers and authors strictly adhering some sort of "canon" which resembles just this outline. Although I am not sure about the true meaning of this answer, I like it.